# Deleting and Adding a replacement EF Entity gives Entity key members cannot be changed error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 3 tables: `Content`, `Language`, and `Content_Language`.
`Content_Language` has two foreign keys, one to `Content` and one to `Language`.

In code, I'm removing one association in Content_Language via:

```
content.Content_Language.Remove(cl);
```

Then adding another (different language, same content record);

```
content.Content_Language.Add(new Content_Language() { LanguageId = 6 };
```

When I call `SaveChanges`, I get:

The value of key member 'ContentId' on an instance of an entity of type 'Content_Language' has changed. Entity key members cannot be changed.

As best I can tell, I'm removing one item and adding another.  Why is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Content_Language` has a composite primary key made up from `LanguageId` and `ContentId`. When you instantiate one like this:
 `new Content_Language() { LanguageId = 6 }`, then you create an instance with a `ContentId` of zero.

You then add it to the `Content_Language` navigation collection, and when EF does it's fix-up it tries to change `ContentId` to the value of `content.Id`. But EF does not let you change primary keys. Hence your error.

You should be able to do this instead:

`var cl = new Content_Language() { LanguageId = 6, ContentId = content.ID }`

You do not need to add it to the `content.Content_Language` collection too because EF fix-up will do that for you